# Issues importing feature class to SDE SQL Server 2012

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, arcgis-10.2

I have received an error indicating there could be issues with my geometry when attempting to import a feature class into SDE. I ran the check geometry tool. No issues.
 I have removed all fields except for my lat/lng, which is a double type, my geometry type, which is point, and objectID.
When doing this, the feature class imports without error.

What could be the issue?

My first guess is having to do with Nulls?

When an objectID doesn't allow null values, does this mean that the feature should be free from nulls in other fields also?

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 and sql server 2012 for my SDE connection.

Comment: please explain version, what tool you are using to import, do you have an sde geodatabase "only" or an sde application server also.

Comment: object ids not allowing nulls is normal. it is not and does not affect nulls in other fields. but you probably have a type mismatch. string into double, int to string. something of the sort.

Comment: @BradNesom what do you mean type mismatch? If the feature class is imported and I select the field type shouldn't it import without error?

Comment: that's why I ask about import tool. so you are not using the load tool. you are importing the table to a brand new table? are you doing that in catalog? are you using the toolbox? are you right clicking? are you drag/dropping? what type is the original data?

Comment: not using the load tool, I tried that and got the same error.   I am trying to import a brand new table with a geometry type as point.  I am doing this in arcmap in the arc catalog window. right clicking the SDE connect and importing feature class, the original data is point data, about 40,000 points.  This data actually was taken from SDE and edited, now parsed data needs to go back into SDE.  The two fields that were added are float types.

Comment: There is a type mismatch with a float and double.  How do I correct this? There is data in the field that is a float, but is being read as a double for some reason.

Comment: Try different methods. Toolbox export to gdb. DragnDrop. Create the table> use the import schema> then load the data. I will post an answer later with screenshots.